# How to join 4 tables in OLEDB in a single statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to join the following 4 tables in a single query with OLEDB because that's the only available method I have at work and I have to make it in one single query. I can use subqueries, but all must be one statement due to the limitations of the software I have available. OLEDB doesn't seem to allow 3 LEFT JOINS no matter how I structure the query. I am using the provider **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0** because again it's the only available provider I have at work.

[Tables Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loV34.png) I used an image because it doesn't let me post it as markdown tables

I get **Error in SQL statement JOIN expression not supported.** The moment I remove the last LEFT JOIN, it works, but I need the last LEFT JOIN to be able to obtain the desired result table. This is my query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        Table1
                        LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Email = Table2.Email
                    )
                    LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.Email = Table3.Email
                )
                LEFT JOIN Table4 ON Table2.Id = Table4.Id
            )
            LEFT JOIN Table4 ON Table3.Id = Table4.Id
        )
    )
```

I have tried a few answers to similar questions asked here, but some of the posts marked as answers don't work in OLEDB. When I have tried the answers I still get **Error in SQL statement JOIN expression not supported.** no matter how I structure the query. The problem is OLEDB has many restrictions and a lot of things that work in many engines or providers, cannot be used in it. Is there a way to achieve the desired table in OLEDB?

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered the question the same day I posted and I marked it as a response, but I don't see the answer anymore. I'll post the solution in hopes that it might help someone having the same question. The last join cannot happen because **Table4** was already used for a join in the previous subquery. The solution was to alias **Table4** to **T4A** and **T4B** on each join respectively to allow for the last join to be possible. Here is the code

```sql
    SELECT
        Username,
        Table1.Email AS Email,
        Switch(T4A.Status IS NULL, T4B.Status, T4A.Status IS NOT NULL, T4A.Status) AS Status
    FROM
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        (
                            Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Email = Table2.Email
                        )
                        LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.Email = Table3.Email
                    )
                    LEFT JOIN Table4 AS T4A ON Table2.Id = T4A.Id
                )
                LEFT JOIN Table4 AS T4B ON Table3.Id = T4B.Id
            )
        )
```

This produces the desired output as shown in the image of the question.